# warning: here-document delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')

Tags: bash, oracle

Пишу скрипт на BASH для ORACLE, который должен включить режим ARCHIVELOG, если он не включен. Но что-то скрипт не работает. Подскажите, где ошибка.

```
host=10.10.0.10
SID='TEST'

VAR1=$(sqlplus / as sysdba <<EOF | grep ARCHIVELOG
set head off pagesize 0 echo off verify off feedback off
select log_mode from v\$database;
exit
EOF)

if [ $VAR1 ]; then echo 'ARCHIVELOG already enabled'
else 
sqlplus / as sysdba <<eof
shutdown immediate;
startup mount;
alter database archivelog;
alter database open;
select log_mode from v\$database;
exit
eof
fi
```

Comment: «не работает» — это малоинформативно. скорее всего, ваша программа выдаёт какие-нибудь сообщения об ошибках и/или предупреждения, содежимое которых совсем не помешало бы привести прямо в вопросе.

Comment: поменял заголовок вопроса на предупреждение, которое, по идее, должна выдавать оболочка (для облегчения последующего поиска теми, кто столкнётся с таким предупреждением).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ошибка как минимум здесь:

```
VAR1=$(sqlplus / as sysdba <<EOF | grep ARCHIVELOG
set head off pagesize 0 echo off verify off feedback off
select log_mode from v\$database;
exit
EOF)
```

here-document, который вы используете, должен (по крайней мере в [posix-совместимых оболочках](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/chap2.html#tag_001_007_004)) заканчиваться строкой, содержащей **только** разделитель:

> line containing only the delimiter, with no trailing blank characters

у вас же разделитель, указанный в начале (<kbd>EOF</kbd>), вообще не совпадает с разделителем, указанным в конце (<kbd>EOF)</kbd>).

перенесите закрывающую скобку на следующую за разделителем строку. чтобы here-document заканчивался так:

```
EOF
)
```